# Error: [$http:baddata] error

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `angularjs` I am trying to learn it. while working with small practice app for `Ajax $http service` I got below error. below is the code I have used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var app=angular.module("angulardata",[]);

app.controller("angulardata",["$scope","$http",function($scope,$http)
{

$http.get('employee.json').then(function(response){

$scope.employees=response;  
});

}]);


    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="angulardata" ng-controller="angulardata">

<h2>Employee Data</h2>
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
<td>{{emp.firstname}}</td>
<td>{{emp.lastname}}</td>
<td>{{emp.Age}}</td>
<td>{{emp.salary}}</td>


</tr>   
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure the url to the json file is correct?

Comment: `$scope.employees=response;` should be `$scope.employees=response.data;`, also double check `.json` URL

Comment: also make sure your file is a valid json

Comment: http://localhost/bootstrap/angular-6.html is may url and json file is also available at same folder like http://localhost/bootstrap/employee.json

below is the json code and it's validated
[
{
firstname:'Gunjan',
lastname:'Limbachiya',
Age:30,
salary:50000
},

{
firstname:'Pramod',
lastname:'Limbachiya',
Age:57,
salary:70000
},

 {
firstname:'Kashyap',
lastname:'Limbachiya',
Age:28,
salary:60000
},
 
 {
firstname:'Malhar',
lastname:'Limbachiya',
Age:30,
salary:220000
},

]

Comment: // JSON Document

[
{
firstname:'Gunjan',
lastname:'Limbachiya',
Age:30,
salary:50000
},

{
firstname:'Pramod',
lastname:'Limbachiya',
Age:57,
salary:70000
},

 {
firstname:'Kashyap',
lastname:'Limbachiya',
Age:28,
salary:60000
},
 
 {
firstname:'Malhar',
lastname:'Limbachiya',
Age:30,
salary:220000
}

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your json file is invalid:
try to use this

```
    [ 
      { "firstname":"Gunjan", "lastname":"Limbachiya", "Age":30, "salary":50000}, 
      { "firstname":"Pramod", "lastname":"Limbachiya", "Age":57, "salary":70000 }, 
      { "firstname":"Kashyap", "lastname":"Limbachiya", "Age":28, "salary":60000 }, 
      { "firstname":"Malhar", "lastname":"Limbachiya", "Age":30, "salary":220000 } 
    ]
```

you can always check if your json is correct here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/